# Eager load multiple levels of records with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following data structure:

`service`

`service_journey`

`service_journey_section`

A `service` has many `service_journeys`. `service_journeys` has many `service_journey_sections`.

I want to eager load all services with all children(`service_journeys`) and grandchildren(`service_journey_sections`).

What I have so far:

`Services::with('service_journeys', 'service_journey_sections')->get();`

However I am worried that this assumes `service_journeys` and `service_journey_sections` are both direct children of a `service` rather than parent, child, grandchild.

Can someone please confirm that either, I am doing it correctly, or correct me where I am going wrong.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Services::with('service_journeys.service_journey_sections')->get();
```

This will eager load all `service_journeys` and `service_journey_sections`